# How to allow only the admin to view link

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I making my Admin User using [Michael Hartl's Rails 3 Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3aadministrative_users).I am making it so my admin user can only see the Index.html.erb for all users. So,  How do I allow my link to be viewed by my admin user only?

This is whats in my UsersController:

```
before_filter :authenticate, :only => [:destroy,:index,:show,:edit, :update]
before_filter :correct_user, :only => [:edit, :update]
before_filter :admin_user,   :only => [:index,:destroy]
.
.
.
.
private
.
.
.       
def admin_user
    authenticate
    redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user.admin?
end
```

This is what i'm trying to edit for Admin to see only:

```
 <% if signed_in? %>        
      <%= link_to "Users", users_path %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Wallinzi, your question is a bit ambiguous. Do you mean the actual code that checks if a user is admin, or do you want to know how to write a unit or integration test for that.  

In any case, we probably need to know about your user model so that we know how you identify your admins, in order to answer this properly.

Comment: Don't worry about the test, i will edit my question for more clarification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write a **helper method** for that so that your views are clean and readable.

*`your_view.html.erb`*

```
<% link_to "Users", users_path if admin? %>
```

*`helpers/application_helper.rb`*

```
def admin?
  @current_user.name == "Mr.Wallinzi"
  # I made up the line above. Implement your own checks according to your setup
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I use account_type as an attribute for a user. So I wrote something like

```
def is_admin
   return true if self.account_type == 1 #The admin account type
end
```

So...

```
<%if signed_in? && @active_user.is_admin %>      
  <%= link_to "Users", users_path %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is for 1 admin for the whole site? The only Admin will be me.

Comment: It really depends on how you discern an admin

Comment: The Admin acts as a user but has other areas included for the admin only ( ban user, delete user,etc).

Comment: You could just set 'self.account_type == 1' into 'is_admin' method.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise), you could easily achieve that in few lines:

1- Add `admin` attribute to Devise table:

a. You can add it using migration: `$ rails generate migration add_admin_to_users admin:boolean`. Your migration will now look like this:

```
  class AddAdminToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change
      add_column :users, :admin, :boolean, :default => false
    end
  end
```

b. Also you can add it to Device table before migration `t.boolean :admin, null: false, default: false`

2- In your view you can this so:

```
<%= link_to "Users", users_path if current_user.admin? %>
```

After you add `admin?` to Devise table it becomes an attribute similar to `email` and others. And it ends with question mark `?` because it's a boolean type.